# JArray update or replace property value

Tags: c#, json

I have a JArray as below, how to JArray ReplaceAll where is_closed=false?
I expect to set is_closed to true and set closed_dt to DateTime.Now for is_closed = false
How to do accomplish this JArray use case scenario with C#?

```
 [
  {
    "oppty": 50,
    "extras": {
    "is_closed": false,
    "closed_dt": ""
  }
},
{
   "oppty": 51,
   "extras": {
     "is_closed": true,
     "closed_dt": ""
   }
 },
 {
    "oppty": 52,
    "extras": {
     "is_closed": false,
     "closed_dt": ""
   }
 }
]
```

I tried C# codes below:

```
 foreach (var oppty in jaOppty.Select(o => o.ToObject<JObject>()).Where(o => (bool)o["extras"]["is_closed"] == false))
   {
     JObject joExtras = (JObject)chat["extras"];
     joExtras["is_closed"] = true;
     joExtras["closed_dt"] = DateTime.Now
    }
```

but it doesn't update the jaOppty, so I thought I have to use ReplaceAll but didn't get an idea on how to do this?

Comment: You question is not clear. pls show us json you are expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
    var jsonParsed = JArray.Parse(json);

    foreach (var item in jsonParsed)
    {
        if (!(bool)item["extras"]["is_closed"])
        {
            item["extras"]["closed_dt"] = DateTime.Now;
            item["extras"]["is_closed"] = true;
        }
    }

    json = jsonParsed.ToString();
```

result

```
[
  {
    "oppty": 50,
    "extras": {
      "is_closed": true,
      "closed_dt": "2022-06-22T10:56:52.3484234-02:30"
    }
  },
  {
    "oppty": 51,
    "extras": {
      "is_closed": true,
      "closed_dt": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "oppty": 52,
    "extras": {
      "is_closed": true,
      "closed_dt": "2022-06-22T10:56:52.351146-02:30"
    }
  }
]
```